# Folha de estilo no input

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma tabela com varias colunas e linhas quero colocar um borda vermelha indicando ate aonde o usuário pode digitar no caso o limite seria a idade.
Já consegui contar quantas vezes a classe cabeçalho aparece, porem quero pegar esse numero e passar na classe "linha1" so pra colocar a borda ate aonde é a idade

```js
$(".nome").on("keyup", function () {
       var i = $('.nome).index(this);
         if ($(".codigo").eq(i).val().length > 0) {
           var j = i + 1;
           var linha = '.linha' + j;

           $(linha).each(function () {
             $(linha).addClass('bordavermelha');
           });

        } else {
          var j = i + 1;
          var linha = '.linha' + j;

          $(linha).each(function () {
              $(linha).removeClass('bordavermelha');
          });
        }
    });
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="cabecalho">Id</td>
        <td class="cabecalho">Nome</td>
        <td class="cabecalho">Idade</td>        
        <td class="cabecalho">Função</td>
        <td class="cabecalho">tempo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input class='nome' id="nome" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha1' id="idade" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha1' id="funcao" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha1' id="tempo" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input class='nome' id="nome" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha2' id="idade" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha2' id="funcao" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha2' id="tempo" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input class='nome' id="nome" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha3' id="idade" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha3' id="funcao" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha3' id="tempo" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: achei o que eu precisava

https://api.jquery.com/each/

com o pause na posição que eu quiser, basta eu fazer aparecer a classe aonde eu quiser

Answer (score 1):

Você não foi muito claro na sua pergunta, não sei se percebi, mas veja se é isto:

CSS e HTML:

```css
 table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 tr:hover {
   border: 2px solid blue;
 }

 .borda-vermelha {
   border: 2px solid red;
 }

 td:hover {
   border: 2px solid gray;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Teste</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table class="linhavermelha">
      <tr>
        <td class="cabecalho">Id</td>
        <td class="cabecalho">Nome</td>
        <td class="cabecalho">Idade</td>
        <td class="cabecalho">Função</td>
        <td class="cabecalho">tempo</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input class='nome borda-vermelha' id="nome" value=""></td>
        <td><input class="linha1 borda-vermelha" id="idade" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha1' id="funcao" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha1' id="tempo" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input class='nome' id="nome" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha2' id="idade" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha2' id="funcao" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha2' id="tempo" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input class='nome' id="nome" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha3' id="idade" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha3' id="funcao" value=""></td>
        <td><input class='linha3' id="tempo" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

Não relacionado a pergunta, mas você possui vários elementos em que tem o mesmo "id":

```
<td><input class='linha1' **id="idade"** value=""></td>
<td><input class='linha2' **id="idade"** value=""></td>
<td><input class='linha3' **id="idade"** value=""></td>
```

Comment: não e com hover. se o usuário começar digitar na input nome, vai aparecer a borda da cor vermelha ate aonde o usuário pode digitar.

Comment: achei o que eu precisava

https://api.jquery.com/each/

com o pause na posição que eu quiser, basta eu fazer aparecer a classe aonde eu quiser